# C++ MFC - CTreeCtrl - Difference between SelectItem and SetItemState

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I need to create a Tree List for my windows application, with multiple selection of nodes with drag-and-drop support. Since Microsoft doesn't provide any such property for the tree which eases the work of the developer, I have to implement this features on my own.

Can somebody explain me the differences (also, the corresponding getters for the following statements) and when to use

```
SetItemState(hItem, 1, TVIS_SELECTED);
```

and

```
SelectItem(hItem);
```

and

```
SetItemState(hItem, TVIS_SELECTED, TVIS_SELECTED);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference is that `SelectItem` is functionally built off of `SetItemState`. Along with anything else it does, `SelectItem` will use `SetItemState` (or equivalent internal calls) to set `TVIS_SELECTED` for the new item, and, say, remove it from the previously selected item.

In order to implement your own multiple-selection control, you have to prevent `SelectItem` from being called when you want to augment the selection instead of replacing it. There are a lot of cases to consider, ranging from mouse clicks with various modifier keys held to keyboard navigation, so good luck in your implementation!

Comment: This is the problem with the closed source softwares. In this case, I am forced to do "non-business logic" code for each mouse click and button press. If it were Java, I would use some third-party APIs and concentrate on the application logic instead.

Comment: @javafan Sure, although if you do it well you can write it once and use it everywhere. Or go buy an implementation that someone else has written; often that gets you lots of capabilities you wouldn't have even considered writing yourself. For all I know there are even open source ones about. Tradeoffs. :)